# Swift Optionals Error

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm getting an error with the following code. It's from data.writeToFile. I've tried photoPath, photoPath!, photoPath?, yet it always gives an error. The error is: extraArgument in the getData call (which isn't the error because when I comment out the data.writeToFile it works fine).

```
let file = object.objectForKey("image") as PFFile
let photoPath = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSTemporaryDirectory())?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("object", isDirectory: true).URLByAppendingPathExtension("jpg")

file.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    data.writeToFile(photoPath!, atomically: true)        
}, progressBlock: { (progress: Int32) -> Void in
    println(progress)
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like Swift is trying to capture the return value of writeToFile() and implicitly return it from the closure. You just have to be explicit about what gets returned here.

```
file.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    data.writeToFile(photoPath!, atomically: true)
    return        
}, progressBlock: { (progress: Int32) -> Void in
    println(progress)
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That was the problem.

Comment: So what is being returned here? `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` seems to expect result block (according to https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFFile.html#//api/name/getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:)?

Comment: Just did. You have to wait a few minutes after asking the question before you can accept, otherwise I would have accepted right away.

Comment: So I get how `(data: NSData!, error: NSError!)` satisfies the result block, I guess I'm failing to see what is being returned by `writeToFile` that it would affect the `in`.  Then again, it's been a long time since I've read the Swift API

Comment: @vol7ron Correct, it expects a result block, with is a closure that takes NSData, and NSError as arguments and returns Void. In this case, Swift was trying to automatically return writeToFile()'s return type (Bool) when Void was expected, leading to a remarkably non-descriptive error message.

Comment: Ahh it returns a Bool. For some reason I also thought *void* could accept any return type, but disregard all values, similar to how *Nulls* function -- clearly I was way off (been a while since I've looked at C/C++/C#/Obj-C).  Thanks,  0x7fffffff.